# Is there a convenient wrapper to get array version of a class?

Tags: python

Assume I have defined a class `MyClass`

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

    def do_something(self):
        ...
        return 'done!'
```

and I want an "array" version of it. That is, something like

```py
class MyClassArray:
    def __init__(self, n, name):
        self._members = [MyClass(name) for _ in range(n)]

    @property
    def _name(self):
        return [member._name for member in self._members]

    def do_something:
        return [member.do_something for member in self._members]
```

The desired things are:

- `MyClassArray` contains a list of different `MyClass` instances, rather than a list of references to the same `MyClass` instance
- Setting an attribute of a `MyClassArray` instance is equivalent to setting the same attribute to all its members
- Getting an attribute of a `MyClassArray` instance is equivalent to getting a list of the same attribute from all its members
- Calling a method of a `MyClassArray` instance is equivalent to calling the same method on all its members.
- Hopefully `myClassArray[i]` returns a ref to the `i`th member in `myClassArray._members`, rather than having to do `myClassArray._members[i]`

My questions are:

- Does Python already have some library that implements this?
- If an existing implementation doesn't exist, what would be the most scalable way to implement it?

Comment: You can implement `__getattr__`, `__setattr__` and `__getitem__`. However "Getting an attribute ... is equivalent to getting a list" and "Calling a method ... is equivalent to calling the same method" are going to be hard to square - methods *are* attributes.

Comment: Try: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.dispatch.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe you mentioned it would be difficult to implement the 'calling a method' feature. I have a simple solution to that below if you wanted to check it out.

Comment: @Allen updated the answer code after testing it.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I looked for any convenient packages that had ready made proxies, I didn't find much. You can write proxies of your own. You'll have to implement several 'magic methods', which you can find documented here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html. I've created a basic proxy that satisfies the requirements you list.

To implement the calling of member methods

- caller invokes a method on proxy.
- proxy looks up the name of the method in `__getattr__()`.
- if found on members, `__getattr__()` wraps the list of function objects in another `MultiProxy` instance and returns it.
- then the `()` operator causes `__call__()` to be invoked on the new proxy.
- new proxy cycles through list of function objects, invoking them.
- new proxy returns a list of return values.

I named the proxy *MultiProxy* because it doesn't really host an "Array" - but it might, or most likely a list.

### A simple object proxy

```
class MultiProxy:
    def __init__(self, members):
        self.__dict__['_members'] = members

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        result = [getattr(member, attr) for member in self._members]
        if result and callable(result[0]):
            return MultiProxy(result)
        return result

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        for member in self._members:
            setattr(member, key, value)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return [member(*args, **kwargs) for member in self._members]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._members)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self._members[index]
```

Any variables that need to be set in the proxy should be set on the `__dict__` directly, otherwise you get infinite recursion in the constructor.

### Test code

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    def do_something(self, msg):
        return f"{self.name}.do_something(msg={msg})"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ar = [TestClass(name) for name in ('bosco', 'ronald', 'ralph', 'sue')]
    mp = MultiProxy(ar)
    print(f"members => {ar}\n")
    print(f"Result of calling mp.do_something('done') => {mp.do_something('done')}")
    print(f"Accessing 'name' property => {mp.name}")
    print(f"Accessing '_name' variable => {mp._name}\n")
    print(f"mp[0] returns => {mp[0]}")
    mp.added_var = "My added var."
    print(f"mp.added_var returns => {mp.added_var}")
```

### Output

```
members => [<__main__.TestClass object at 0x10a6d0190>, <__main__.TestClass object at 0x10a6dd0a0>, <__main__.TestClass object at 0x10a736850>, <__main__.TestClass object at 0x10a736f40>]

Result of calling mp.do_something('done') => ['bosco.do_something(msg=done)', 'ronald.do_something(msg=done)', 'ralph.do_something(msg=done)', 'sue.do_something(msg=done)']
Accessing 'name' property => ['bosco', 'ronald', 'ralph', 'sue']
Accessing '_name' variable => ['bosco', 'ronald', 'ralph', 'sue']

mp[0] returns => <__main__.TestClass object at 0x10a6d0190>
mp.added_var returns => ['My added var.', 'My added var.', 'My added var.', 'My added var.']
```